# Use a parent class init inside of a class protocol that conforms to a class

Tags: swift

I am using SpriteKit to create a game and I am trying to create a system of inheritance for SprikeKit object nodes by subclassing them. This is my current situation:

```
protocol Node: SKNode {}

protocol SpriteNode: SKSpriteNode, Node {
    static var size: CGSize {get}
}

extension SpriteNode {
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.init(texture: SKTexture(name, color: UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0), size: Self.size)
    }
}


class Platform: SKSpriteNode, SpriteNode {
    static var size: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
    }

    init() {
        self.init(texture: SKTexture("platform.png"), color: .image, size: Self.size)
    }

}
```

I am attempting to use the implementation provided in the SpriteNode protocol to initialize my Platform class, this is the way I would only have to do `Platform()`.

For example I used to have this init inside of my Platform and it worked as expected:

```
class Platform: SKSpriteNode, SpriteNode {
    static var size: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(texture: SKTexture("platform.png"), color: .image, size: Self.size)
    }

}
```

Here is my extension of SKTexture as well:

```
extension SKTexture {
    convenience init(_ name: String) {
        self.init(imageNamed: name)
        filteringMode = .nearest
    }
}
```

Since that init would have to be copied and pasted into every single class that conforms to SpriteNode, I want to put it in the protocol itself to avoid all that boilerplate code.

Is this even possible or the right approach in the first place?

Thank you so much, any help and insight is appreciated. I'm new to swift.

Comment: Please use real code, not fake expressions like `init(singleParam)`.

Comment: The exact type and code isn't really relevant in this question so I thought psuedo code would suffice to get my point across. However, in the future I'll make sure to use real, compile-able code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. No protocol needed! Just extend SKSpriteNode and inherit:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var image : UIColor {
        UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    }
}
extension SKTexture {
    convenience init(_ s:String) {
        self.init(imageNamed:s)
    }
}

extension SKSpriteNode {
    @objc class var size: CGSize { .zero } // override me for subclass
    convenience init(_ name: String) {
        self.init(texture: SKTexture(name), color: .image, size: Self.size)
    }
}

// example
class Platform: SKSpriteNode {
    override class var size: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
    }
}
```

And now you are able to say `let p = Platform("yoho")`, which is what I believe we were aiming at.

Comment: Note the use of `class var` so that we can continue to inherit and override `size`. (Like what if Platform has a subclass?) If you say `static` you can't override.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic and important rule of Swift class initializers is that a subclass that declares a designated initializer ceases to inherit initializers from its superclass.

Okay, so when you gave LowLevel an initializer `init()`, you prevented inheritance of initializers from TopLevel. Therefore LowLevel does not inherit `init(param1, param2, param3)` from TopLevel. Therefore it cannot *call* `self.init(param1, param2, param3)` — there is no such method in `self`. The existence of the protocol cannot magically change that.

Comment: But if I have a protocol that extends a class I should be able to access the super inits somehow, just like how I'd be able to do super.init(param1, param2, param3) from LowLevel. Is there any way to access super inits from a protocol that extends a class?

Comment: First of all your code never says `super.init` (in fact the term `super` never appears at all), so why do you mention it now? Second, there is no meaningful sense of “should” in which a protocol “should” pervert the rules of inheritance and initializers. And third, I honestly have no meaning to attach to the phrase “a protocol that extends a class”. And fourth, I have no idea what you think your code is trying to do; I simply tried to say why, if it were real, it wouldn’t compile (though it isn’t real so the attempt is kind of pointless).

Comment: As you can tell I am new to swift so I don't know the proper terminology, sorry. I mention super as I am attempting to use the init in a superclass inside of the protocol. I used the word "should" because In my limited understanding of the situation, there *should* be a way to be able to do what I'm doing. I don't know swift terminology and when I said "protocol extends a class" I mean a protocol that includes "Protocol: Class". Thank you for your insight and I did learn from your comments, what Im essentially trying to do is make a protocol init that uses a init inside of a class it includes.

Comment: I don't know what "use the init in a superclass inside of the protocol" means; a protocol doesn't have a superclass (it's a protocol, not a class). I don't know what "inside of a class it includes" means either, I'm sorry. And I do not know what the phrase "there should be a way to be able to do what I'm doing" means because I don't know what you're doing. I'm sorry I've failed to grasp the purpose of the fake code. Next time, if you were to use _real_ code and say exactly what you wish would happen when it runs, that would be most helpful.

Comment: I rewrote my post with my specific situation to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better question!

Comment: Sorry, `.image` is just a static UIColor that is red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0